# The type 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics

my Class:

```
public static class Global
{
    public static void TextBoxEmpty<T>(T ContainerControl) where T : ContainerControl
    {
        foreach (var t in ContainerControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            t.Text = string.Empty; 
        }
    }
}
```

use :

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Global.TextBoxEmpty<GroupBox>(this.grpInfoBook);
}
```

error :

> The type 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Global.TextBoxEmpty(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion
>   from 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl'.

What is the correct code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need the `where` restriction at all since in the code you're using `OfType` to filter the list anyways.  However, if you want to keep the restriction, change it to reference `System.Windows.Controls.Control`:

```
public static class Global
{
    public static void TextBoxEmpty<T>(T ContainerControl) where T : Control
    {
        foreach (var t in ContainerControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            t.Text = string.Empty; 
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the docs for `GroupBox` and you'll see it does not inherit from `ContainerControl`:

```
System.Object
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    System.Windows.DependencyObject
      System.Windows.Media.Visual
        System.Windows.UIElement
          System.Windows.FrameworkElement
            System.Windows.Controls.Control
              System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl
                System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl
                  System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance hierarchy of GroupBox is:

```
  System.Object 
    System.MarshalByRefObject
      System.ComponentModel.Component
        System.Windows.Forms.Control
          System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
```

The type ContainerControl is not in this inheritance tree, hence the reason for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The generic constraint, you have defined restricts the usage to ContainerControl type. But GroupBox is not a containercontrol. It derives from Control class.